How to determine if taskbar pinning will trigger a notification or be silent on win10
I am working with Chromium code and want to pin the shortcut to the taskbar. Like in this photo:

On Win11, the notification appears always, which is great. But on some Win10 the shortcut is pinned silently to the taskbar without that notification appearing, which is not what I want.
I tested on multiple Win10 with the same version (colleagues' PCs), the behaviour is different. I am pretty sure is a OS thing.
Is there a way (hidden API, registry key, etc) to determine whether the Windows will show the notification or pin silently?
P.S. I am using C++
